# parametrization of a specific algebraic surface

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I consider the surface of degree $5$ of equation:
$$ 4 x y - 4 x^3 y - 4 x y^3 + z + 2 x^2 z + x^4 z + 2 y^2 z + 
 2 x^2 y^2 z + y^4 z - 4 x y z^2 - 6 z^3 + 2 x^2 z^3 + 2 y^2 z^3 + z^5=0 $$

Question: is this surface rational -- is there a parametrization for this surface using rational functions of two variables?

A more general question would be whether there is a parametrization using some special functions.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is an affine patch of a surface of general type in $\mathbb P^3$, so it is not rational. What do you mean by 'special funtions'?

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! About special functions: I've read somewhere that hypergeometric functions could solve some quintics.